# How do I objectively compare the performance of different CDNs?

Tags: cdn

Is there a way that I can objectively compare the performance of different CDNs? Will I need to purchase a plan and test it out myself?

Comment: Most companies let you set up a short term trial for free.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [article](http://blog.mudy.info/tag/cdn-comparison/) that compares the latency between a number of different CDNs. Their results may be a little out of date, but you can redo the tests if you`d like using the same 
[ping website](http://just-ping.com/) they did.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to objectively test a CDN is by using a monitoring service that's geographically diverse and on diverse networks that can mimic your application loads.

A good CDN will get content to your users at lower latency and with fewer hops than going all that way back to your origin servers.

For a web site, that typically means web page loads.

You didn't specify your application, so I'm assuming web site.

Companies like Gomez and Keynote (there are many others -- see some below, but those are the old time heavyweights-- most $$$$)  offer services that track how well a webpage will load under a variety of parameters.  For US focused sites, I usually like to check from 6 regions in the US. (Seattle, LA, Chicago, Dallas, Boston, Miami)..  If you care a lot about international traffic you can set up probes abroad too.

You also want to setup probes on different ISPs.  How well a CDN works for customers with Comcast might be very different from how it looks to customers on  Level 3.  Having a mix of top tier and 'eyeball' networks is good. (monitoring companies already have probes on a variety of networks)

Be careful with these services.  They tend to charge per probe you hit, and while you may think that checking every 5 minutes is cool, it will soon cost you.  Consider it a development tool to track long term trends and only turn up the frequency when you're A/B testing CDNs. (better yet, set up a different URLs for each CDN you are testing and let the same probes hits all of them.)

If you have some Javascript-FU, you can bypass a lot of what these services offer and set up your pages to report back to you about their load characteristics from user's browsers. (best to do a sampling, not EVERY page load)
Couple that with a GeoIP database, and you can get some good baseline data to start with..
Here's someone doing that...  [HTML5 method for page load measuring](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/)

Cheaper alternatives to Gomez and Keynote:
Pingdom
WebpageTest
Siteuptime
AlertSite

I've had good luck with AlertSite in the recent past.

Cheers,

Joel